# Reset of the acronym with glossaries-extra

Tags: macros, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I would like to set up a glossary using the package glossaries-extra in such a way that the acronyms would be displayed in full at the beginning of each chapters for their first appearance and then only the acronym would appear.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossary

\newacronym{lmi}{LMI}{Linear Matrix Inequality}

\begin{document}
\printglossary

Hello world

\chapter{First}
First use: \gls{lmi}
Second use: \gls{lmi}

\chapter{Second}
First use: \gls{lmi}
Second use: \gls{lmi} 

\end{document}
```

Basically, in the code above, I am looking for a macro that displays:
Linear Matrix Inequality (LMI) for the first appearance in a chapter and then simply LMI for the next appearances.

Thanks.

Romain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest method is to add `\glsresetall` to the start of each chapter with `etoolbox`'s `\preto` command. (`etoolbox` is automatically loaded by `glossaries` and therefore by `glossaries-extra` but I've loaded it explicitly below for clarity.)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries-extra}

\preto\chapter{\glsresetall}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\newacronym{lmi}{LMI}{Linear Matrix Inequality}

\begin{document}
\printglossary

Hello world

\chapter{First}
First use: \gls{lmi}
Second use: \gls{lmi}

\chapter{Second}
First use: \gls{lmi}
Second use: \gls{lmi}

\end{document}
```

First chapter:

[image: Chapter 1 First. First use: Linear Matrix Inequality (LMI) Second use: LMI]

Second chapter:

[image: Chapter 2 Second. First use: Linear Matrix Inequality (LMI) Second use: LMI]

Comment: Nowadays one doesn't need to load `etoolbox` and instead could use `\AddToHook{cmd/chapter/pre}{\glsresetall}` instead of `\preto`

Comment: @Skillmon Nowadays it would be `cmd/chapter/before`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Anyone interested in combining per chapter resetting with entry unit counting, check https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646628/105447. (Nicola, if you think the use case is interesting as an example in the documentation, feel free to use it).

Comment: @gusbrs yes, that would be the correct name now ;)

Comment: @Skillmon Nowadays I shouldn't be making typo puns.  :)  I just left a note for the benefit of other people, as I was myself bitten by it, since I though "It's Skillmon's, it must be right", and it took me some time to figure it out. ;-)